# MySql crashes multiple times in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Multisite mysql getting crashed multiples times.

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/xxxxxxxx/www/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1925
PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Error reading result set's header in /home/xxxxxxxx/www/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1925
PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /home/xxxxxxxx/www/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531'
```

I don't find anything suspicious in the log

```
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'myisam-recover' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'myisam-recover-options' instead.
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.9G
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=795526465769
2020-02-06  6:18:28 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
2020-02-06  6:18:29 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 11 pages from redo log
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 67151849, file name ./mysql-bin.007416
2020-02-06  6:18:29 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-02-06  6:18:29 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-02-06  6:18:29 140544489782656 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.36-82.1 started; log sequence number 795526513845
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140539223574272 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140544489782656 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140544489782656 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140544489782656 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140544489782656 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140544489782656 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-02-06  6:18:30 140544489782656 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 9.1
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How comes this happen? did change anything like prefix of wordpress, changes made to mysql or php version or any changes to server? may be those are the issues. Please provide the related information. Its due to corrupted database.

1. find wp-db.php and add this line $this->query("set session wait_timeout=300"); after $this->ready = true;
2. goto wp-config.php and add define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
3. goto https://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php and click repair your database
4. or simply upload old backup